# Can we show some reports like Table data like rows and columns in Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: chatbot, azure-language-understanding, botframework

I am building an Azure LUIS chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework, where I have to show some reports in tables in the chatbot itself based on the user input.

Can we do it in the Microsoft bot framework?

Please guide

Comment: What is an Azure LUIS chatbot? Do you mean a Bot Framework bot? What channel are you using?

Comment: @KyleDelaney: I'd assume it's a Microsoft Bot Framework app built using the Azure Bot Service and relying on Azure Cognitive Services' [Language Understanding (LUIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/what-is-luis) natural language processing service.

Comment: Since your question relates to outputting reports, I'd assume this has less to do with LUIS and more to do with the Microsoft Bot Framework. Meaning, this question would likely stand regardless of whether or not you're using LUIS. You might want to rephrase your question and your tags to clarify that, in order to ensure this gets out in front of the right audience.

Comment: Apologize. Edited my Post...Yes, I'm using Microsoft Bot Framework. Please guide if this possible in the same? @JeremyCaney

Comment: @KyleDelaney the channel would be the website. Yes, Microsoft Bot Framework.. Please guide.

Comment: @Developer - Do you mean you're using Web Chat perhaps?

Comment: @Developer  - Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Thanks for following up with this to me. Yes, I'm working, and I found adaptive cards as the solution for the same.

Comment: @Developer - That's great, would you like to post that as an answer?